Error in flutter_face_api_beta Dependency: Unknown Kotlin JVM Target 21
/Users/pro/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/camera_android_camerax-0.6.9+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/camerax/PreviewHostApiImpl.java:86: warning: [removal] onSurfaceCreated() in Callback has been deprecated and marked for removal
              public void onSurfaceCreated() {
                          ^
1 warning

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':flutter_face_api_beta:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Error while evaluating property 'compilerOptions.jvmTarget' of task ':flutter_face_api_beta:compileDebugKotlin'.
   > Failed to calculate the value of property 'jvmTarget'.
      > Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21

